# Return value Pair of n-nested Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which can be nested multiple times. However, always two arrays with two entries each are at the end of each "nesting". I always need the two entries from the two arrays at the end of each nesting returned.

Here is an example:

```
const arr = [
    [
        [1, 2], [3, 4]
    ], [
        [5, 6], [7, 8]
    ], [
        [
            [9, 10], [11, 12]
        ], [
            [14, 15], [16, 17]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Here is the expected result:

```
const return1 = [
    { a: 1, b: 2 },
    { a: 3, b: 4 }
];
const return2 = [
    { a: 5, b: 6 },
    { a: 7, b: 8 }
];
const return3 = [
    { a: 9, b: 10 },
    { a: 11, b: 12 }
];
const return4 = [
    { a: 13, b: 14 },
    { a: 15, b: 16 }
];
```

Everything I find online is how to reduce an n-nested array to a flat array, something like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

Comment: is `return..` also an array?

Comment: Yes. As written there. An `array` of `objects`

Comment: why not return an array of arrays with objects as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map with an iterative and recursive approach while checking nested arrays.

```js
var array = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]], [[[9, 10], [11, 12]], [[14, 15], [16, 17]]]],
    result = array.reduce(function iter(r, a) {
        return r.concat(Array.isArray((a[0] || [])[0])
            ? a.reduce(iter, [])
            : [a.map(([a, b]) => ({ a, b }))]
        );
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

With custom recursive function:

```js
var arr = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]], [[[9, 10], [11, 12]], [[14, 15], [16, 17]]]],
result = [],
get_pairs = function(arr, r){
    arr.forEach(function(v){
        if (Array.isArray(v)) {
     if (!Array.isArray(v[0])) {
         var o = {a: v[0], b: v[1]};
         (!r.length || r[r.length-1].length==2)? r.push([o]) : r[r.length-1].push(o);
     } else {
         get_pairs(v, r);
     }   
        }
    });  
};

get_pairs(arr, result);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Spent to much time in this. However, here is a very messy looking code.

There is this recursive function that checks if a given array is in the form `[[number, number],[number, number]]`. If so, it adds an object to the variable `returnArray` that we are knowingly mutating.

If it is not in the form, we just check for the items inside the array.

```js
const arrInput = [
  [[1, 2], [3, 4]], 
  [[5, 6], [7, 8]], 
  [
   [[9, 10], [11, 12]], 
   [[14, 15], [16, 17]],
  ],
];
function mapArrayToObj(arr, returnArray = []) {
  if (arr.length === 2 && typeof arr[0][0] === "number" && 
      typeof arr[0][1] === "number" && typeof arr[1][0] === "number" &&
      typeof arr[1][1] === "number") {
         returnArray.push([
            { a: arr[0][0], b: arr[0][1] }, 
            { a: arr[1][0], b: arr[1][1] }
         ]);
  } else {
         arr.forEach((item) => { mapArrayToObj(item, returnArray); });
  }
  return returnArray;
}
console.log(mapArrayToObj(arrInput));
```